# How to convert PNGs to GIF with very short delay in Python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, gif, image-conversion

The only similar thread I found on this is [Gif Frame Duration Seems Slower Than Expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64473278/gif-frame-duration-seems-slower-than-expected) which somewhat captured my problem, but the 'solution' doesn't work.

My problem is that I am using Pillow to convert PNGs to GIF with the following code:

```
frames = [Image.open("_bg0.png"), Image.open("_bg1.png"), Image.open("_bg2.png"), Image.open("_bg3.png")]

frames[0].save('_test.gif', format='GIF',
               append_images=frames[1:],
               save_all=True,
               disposal = 2,
               duration=4, loop=0, transparency=0)
```

I want the duration to be 4ms, however the output looks *much* slower than this. Here is an example (top is Pillow, bottom is EzGif, same delay specified).

[image: Using Pillow]

[image: Using EzGif]

I saw it has something to do with the frame rate, however everything I tried in the linked thread didn't work (particularly setting a value slightly above 1). I've tried setting it to 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and many values in between.

How do I fix this? I want to be able to do this conversion in Python.

Comment: This answer suggests that a duration that is too short is ignored by modern browsers.  Maybe try duration=20 and see what happens?  The linked answer said that that 1/100 (10ms) is too short, but 2/100 (20ms) works.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/64530622

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I set mine to 20 ms (I had tried 2/100 ms rather than 2/100 s which caused the issue described earlier).

This has fixed the problem, and indeed there was already a 'speed cap' when using EzGif I just didn't realise.

Comment: I think you mean you tried 2ms, not 2/100ms, which is 20us.